# Installation Folder URL in Click Once Publish Window - VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, excel-addins

What will do the Installation Folder URL will do while publishing the application?

I read so many articles got confused.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Installation Folder URL" in a Click-Once deployment is specific to deploying to a web server. If you're deploying to a file share you don't need to use it.

As an example, I published one of my Add-Ins to a GitHub repository.

Note: The setup.exe will use the "Installation Folder URL" as the install path.

[image]

Comment: So that if user try to install your vsto addin, installation will download from that location?

Comment: Yes, but since I generated my certificate from Visual Studio, the certificate has to be installed/trusted on the machine, before the install will run. If you sign with a valid certificate from a trusted authority (a paid certificate, not a self-signed one) the install should run with no problem.

Comment: Here's one of the sites you can use to get a signed certificate. http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/

Comment: Is publishing folder location is local directory?

Comment: Yes, In the example I posted, I first publish to the local folder "publish\", then I check-in my project to GitHub. After that, the setup.exe can be downloaded from GitHub and it will install from the URL path.

Comment: Yes, But I could not succeeded with ftp server path as Installation Folder URL.

Comment: Finally I have done publishing my application in FTP server, now how can I install that in local PC

Comment: Download and run the setup.exe file from the ftp site.

Comment: Yes, I did that but next version updates are not effecting in local PC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165140/discussion-between-aduguid-and-rama-krishna).

Comment: While you don't need to use this when publishing to a share, there is a reason to do so; if you try to open a document created using a document-level add-in, it will go out and install it from that location. Otherwise, you'll get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents and in addition to @aduguid's answer, I'd like to add that the URL is case sensitive

Let's say my URL in VS is:

```
http://myserver/mycooltool/
```

If I tried installing from:

```
http://myserver/MyCoolTool/
```

I got the error:

> An error occurred attempting to install MyCoolTool